# Problem in Bézier curves with pgfplots for relative negative coordinates

Tags: pgfplots, relative, bezier

I attempted to plot some Bézier curves in a `pgfplots` graph. This works well when the coordinates are positive. See:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[ axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
 xmin = 0, xmax = 11, ymin = 0, ymax=4,
 unit vector ratio=1 1, grid,
 xlabel = $x$, ylabel = $y$]
   \draw[blue, thick] (axis cs:1,1.5)
   .. controls (axis cs:1.2,2.5) and +(axis cs:-0.5,0) ..
   (axis cs:2,3.5)coordinate(A)
   .. controls +(axis cs:0.5,0) and +(axis cs:-6,0) ..
   (axis cs:11,1.55);
   \draw[red,<->] (A) +(axis cs:-0.8,0) --+(axis cs:0.8,0);
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

The problem is when I try the same thing for negative x coordinates (despite the use of `axis direction cs` syntax):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
 xmin = -11, xmax = 0, ymin = 0, ymax=4,
 unit vector ratio=1 1, grid,
 xlabel = $x$, ylabel = $y$]
      \draw[blue, thick] (axis cs:-1,1.5)
   .. controls (axis direction cs:-1.2,2.5) and +(axis direction cs:0.5,0) ..
   (axis cs:-2,3.5)coordinate(B)
   .. controls +(axis direction cs:-0.5,0) and +(axis direction cs:6,0) ..
   (axis cs:-11,1.55);
   \draw[red,<->] (B) +(axis direction cs:-0.8,0) --+(axis direction cs:0.8,0);
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are mixing `axis direction cs:` and `axis cs:` coordinates.

Comment: @marmot I primarily used `axis cs:` and the result was incorrect. Reading the doc (part 4.17.1) I've found that `axis direction cs:` is dedicated to relative coordinates... with no success (the result is slightly different though).

Comment: When I run your second example on my machine, I do not get the result you show. Please notice also that there is a common misconception: if you add `++ (axis cs:0,0)` to a path this does not necessarily coincide with adding `++ (0,0)`because the origin of the axis is in general not the origin of the embedding `tikzpicture`.

Comment: Sorry, the published version of the code was not exactly the one that gave the image. Now it's correct and your primary comment was right : I've defined with `axis direction` an absolute coordinate. With this correction it's working as expected! Do I have to delete my question?

Comment: No, you do not have to delete it. If you want you could write an answer which explains these pitfalls such that others learn from it.

Comment: Actually, it was just a mistake I was not able to see despite careful reading... I'm not sure there is anything to learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple: as @marmot pointed out in the comments, there was a mistake: I was using `axis direction cs` in a non-relative coordinate definition. Applying this correction the code worked as expected:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
 xmin = -11, xmax = 0, ymin = 0, ymax=4,
 unit vector ratio=1 1, grid,
 xlabel = $x$, ylabel = $y$]
    \draw[blue, thick] (axis cs:-1,1.5)
   .. controls (axis cs:-1.2,2.5) and +(axis direction cs:0.5,0) .. % replacement
   (axis cs:-2,3.5)coordinate(B)
   .. controls +(axis direction cs:-0.5,0) and +(axis direction cs:6,0) ..
   (axis cs:-11,1.55);
   \draw[red,<->] (B) +(axis direction cs:-0.8,0) --+(axis direction cs:0.8,0);
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]